# MTOM (XOP) file size limit in SoapUI

Tags: soapui, mtom

We use SoapUI for testing of Web Services. It acts as a mock service. Our application sends requests with MTOM attachment. If this attachment is smaller than 6882 B, everything is all right. If it is bigger only a part of it is received by SoapUI - in attachment tab (of Message Viewer in SoapUI) is size 6882 B and when it is exported to the file, broken file is created.

Is there some file size limit or configuration for requests which can be received by SoapUI? Has anybody an experience in sending of XOP (MTOM) attachment which is bigger than 6882 B to SoapUI?

Comment: Do you mean, you trying to save the attachment which is part of response? what is the file type (extension)?

Comment: The attachment is a part of request. Its file type is ZIP (zipped text file).

Comment: If it is part of request, soapui will be able to send it successfully. I believe, there isn't any limit on the file size from soapui side. Hope there is no limit defined on your application size. Also you mentioned that it is borken when exported -  what do you mean?

Comment: It is a request from our application which is send to SoapUI (mock service). Its attachment is exported through "export" button in attachment tab in SoapUI.

Comment: Are you saving the attachment to file in mock request? Is that what your problem is ?

Comment: Our application send (standard) request which contains MTOM attachment. This request is received by mock service in SoapUI. I want to check the attachment of the request (in SoapUI). So, I open this received request via the "Message Log" tab (in SoapUI). There is the "Attachment" tab (for Request Message). The displayed size in this tab is 6882 B for each attachment (if it is not smaller). The same size has the file which I get when I export it from SoapUI.

Comment: I tried to send a request through HTTP (instead of HTTPS). I disabled SSL for transport layer on both our app and SoapUI. Then the received attachment was all right (bigger than 6882 B).

Comment: Are you ok to have a script which can save the attachment automatically? If so, can show the raw request which you send?

Comment: Do you aware of these configuration in your application             <multipart-config>
      <!-- 50MB max -->
      <max-file-size>69127739</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>69127739</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>   and are you sure apart from soapui anywhere else you were able to receive entire attachment that your application sends

Comment: I am using mock and i have sent an 1163252 B pdf document and i am able to receive and able to download from soapui mock request attachments tab with out any breakage

Comment: Please check if [this](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Saving-attachments-automatically/m-p/880/highlight/true#M229) helps to save attachments automatically. Note that `messageExchange.response` is replaced with the relevant code in mock script.

Comment: I tried to create script in SoapUI to save attachments automatically. The saved file has 6882 B again.
Also I implemented my own mock service and received file was all right.
I found that [the same problem](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Multipart-requests-to-a-mock-service-under-SSL-appear-to-be/td-p/114786) had somebody else and it was connected with SSL too. Unfortunately, there is not any solution yet.